# Foreign field reference in Sequelize model files

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am writing a lead capture app using nodejs, express and sequelize. I have a Lead object, but I want to introduce a new table LeadSource to the schema, with Lead having a FK to LeadSource

#### /path/to/model/Lead.js

```
'use strict';

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var Lead = sequelize.define('Lead', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,

      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    first_name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },    
    last_name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },       
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
    },
  });

  return Lead;
};
```

#### This is the schema for LeadSource

```
LeadSource = sequelize.define('LeadSource', {
  id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER },
  name: { type: Sequelize.STRING }
});
```

My questions are:

1. How do I reference LeadSource as FK in the Lead.js file?
2. I like to keep each model in a seperate file - can I have this separation and still have LeadSource reference by a FK in Lead?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can define the relationships between the models while keeping each one in a separate file.

Here is how you can define [associations](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html) between Lead and LeadSource in `Lead.js` file

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    var Lead = sequelize.define('Lead', {
        // ...
    })

    Lead.associate = function (models) {
        // associations can be defined here

        //One-To-One relationship with foreign key added to Lead
        Lead.belongsTo(models.LeadSource, {
            foreignKey: { name: 'leadSourceId' }
        })

        //One-To-Many relationship with foreign key added to Lead
        models.LeadSource.hasMany(Lead, {
            foreignKey: { name: 'leadSourceId' }
        })
    }

    return Lead;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you explain why you have both a *One-To-One* and *One-To-Many* in the `associate()` method? Also, you are using models.LeadSource, but I don't see you importing this anywhere in your code?

Comment: This is just an example, you can define several relationships between your models, it depends on what association types exist between them. `models` is a parameter of the `associate()` function, see this example https://github.com/sequelize/express-example/blob/master/models/user.js from the `sequelize` repo